# DNS not resolving some websites properly

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

From the network in our office, some websites are not getting resolved to their proper IP addresses. I guess it is a problem with our DNS server because, when I changed it to Google's public DNS, I was able to access all the websites. What is the solution?

Comment: welcome to [security.se] - but why are you asking this question here? Please see the [FAQ] - this site is for security questions.

Comment: This question needs much more detail if we're to offer you any insight.

Comment: If you could tell me what details, I'll give it to you. I am sorry I am new here.

Comment: How about: What DNS server are you running internally? How is it configured for forwarders and/or root hints? What is the configuration on the clients? What are the clients; Windows, Linux, etc. ?

Comment: Operating system, DNS software, configured forwarders, local zones, DNS configuration, network infrastructure, possible firewalls, ... . If you think something else could be valuable don't hesitate to provide this, too.

Comment: It is a cisco server.. The clients are windows. I dont know the rest of the details. I am sorry. I am a programmer, and I dont know much about sys admin.

Comment: @Brahadeesh: It sounds to me that you need to get a sysadmin to take a look at this.. managing servers isnt something you learn in 30 minutes.

Comment: @pauska was afraid of it. I thought I'd try this on my own before troubling our admin guy. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have created the a-records/domain on your internal DNS servers. Try doing start -> run -> nslookup

```
Server dnsserver1

Mysite.com
```

Do all DNS servers resolve the website to the same IP address? Check your hosts file. Are you using correct DNS forwarders or Root servers? Properties on the DNS servers...

Comment: I'll ask my admin guy to look through this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at changing the name server for your network (e.g. at the router). I see this issue regularly with the DNS servers of a certain ISP with a name that rhymes with Vindspream. ;-)

Comment: Could you give me a link where there are step by step instructions on how to do this ? Am a newbie.

Comment: If the problem is with the ISP name servers, then you want to lookup the make and model of your router with keywords like "change DNS server" etc. You may prefer contacting the ISP support and they should be able to step you through this, assuming you can reach a human being by phone.

Comment: Thank you, will do that, though I think the sarcasm is unwarranted.

Comment: The sarcasm was directed towards the support line. It is often difficult to reach a human being when calling for support. Not directed towards you my friend. :-)

Comment: Oh. sorry then. Yeah they are difficult to reach :)